# NSResponder mouseExited when hovering Window title

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsresponder

I have an NSWindow with an NSToolbar and a content view.
I have set the tracking area to be the whole frame of the view.

I wish to have the mouseExited event fired when the cursor leaves the content view and enters the toolbar and/or the window title. What is the best way to achieve this? should I bound the tracking area to just below the toolbar?

The main reason I need this is because my view needs a special cursor. So I'm changing it in mouseEntered and wish to change it again when mouseExited

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [add a cursor rectangle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/addCursorRect%3acursor%3a) over [the entire bounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/bounds) of the view?

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't seem to work as I want. For some reason the cursor doesn't change back to the regular once I exit the view